# Trying to find numbers repeated in two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to find all of the numbers that are repeated across two arrays..
For example:

```
array1[2]:    1,2 

array2[2]:    1,5
```

The number that repeats itself is `1` so we create a new array that will contain `1`.

```
array3[2]:    1
```

My code is:

```
int func1(int  *str, int *str2)
{
    int i,j,temp,c[10];
    for(i=0;i<*(str+i);i++){
        for(j=0;j<*(str2+j);j++){
            if(*(str+i) == *(str+j))
            {
                temp = *(str+i);
                *(str+i) = temp;
                temp = *(c+i);
                return c[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem?(logically)

Thanks.

Comment: You're only returning one character, not an array. If you don't match, you're defaulting to return 0... You're not bounds checking str/str1.. how do you know when they end...

Comment: `i<*(str+i)` <-- what are you doing here and why?

Comment: What is the problem you are actually seeing? Does it crash, or run but produce an incorrect answer?

Comment: As you'll notice from answers and misguided retagging attempts, people are confused by the names `str1` and `str2` being used for integer arrays instead of character strings.  Generally, names like `str1` should refer to strings, not integer arrays.

Comment: This is probably an evolution of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121179/function-that-search-difference-between-members-of-array

Comment: @sdsdsdsdas why don't you go back and edit the original question, and close this one?

Comment: @forsvarir, @sverre: the evolution of 6121179 into this question is contorted - I think the new question (this one) is warranted.  All else apart, the other question is dealing with a single array; this deals with two arrays.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I agree a new question was reasonable (which is why I didn't flag it as a duplicate), however there was significant overlap in the approach (particuarly the for loop boundary checking), which is why I linked to it.  Excellent answer btw.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems:

1. The conditions in the two `for` loops are odd and probably wrong.  They are equivalent to:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < str1[i]; i++)
       for (j = 0; j < str2[j]; j++)
   ```
2. You should probably specify the sizes of the input arrays in the function interface.
3. In C, you must make sure you always know the sizes of the arrays.
4. You should probably specify the output array in the function interface.
5. Since you will need to know how many values were found in common, you'll need to return that number from the function.
6. Your choice of the names `str1` and `str2` is unusual.  Not technically wrong, but probably not a good idea.  Such names should be reserved for character strings, not arrays of integers.
7. Your local array `c` is barely used, and is not used safely.
8. Your code returns when it finds the first pair of numbers that match, not all possible matches.
9. The first two lines of the body of the `if` statement elaborately copies the value in `str[i]` back to itself via `temp`.
10. The third line of the body of the `if` statement copies an uninitialized value from array `c` into the variable `temp`.
11. The last line of the body of the `if` then returns that uninitialized value.

This adds up to changes such as:

```
int func1(int *arr1, int num1, int *arr2, int num2, int *arr3)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < num2; j++)
        {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j])
                arr3[k++] = arr1[i];
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Note that this code assumes that the size of `arr3` (the array, not the pointer itself) is as big as the product of `num1` and `num2`.  If both arrays contain a list of the same value, then there will be one row in the output array, `arr3`, for each pair so it could use `num1 * num2` rows.  This points out that the code does not deal with suppressing duplicates; if you need that (you likely do), then the body of the `if` statement needs to search through the current values in `arr3` to check that the new value is not present.  It would be wise to add another parameter, `int siz3`, to indicate the size of the third array; if you run out of space for values, you could then return -1 as an error indication.

The coded algorithm is quadratic (or, more accurately, proportional to the product `num1 * num2`).  If you know the arrays are sorted on entry, you can reduce it to a linear algorithm (proportional to `num1 + num2`).  With duplicate elimination, it is a little more expensive - it isn't quite as simple as 'cubic'.  If you know the input arrays contain unique values (no duplicates), then duplicate elimination is obviously not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(i=0;i<*(str+i);i++){
        for(j=0;j<*(str2+j);j++){
```

Are wrong. You are applying '<' condition on an integer to itself and hence loop condition breaks. So, the loop never runs.

And why are you using these redundant statements?

```
 temp = *(str+i);
 *(str+i) = temp;
```

Also, this is wrong

```
temp = *(c+i);
return c[i];
```

Try more to correct those statements.If you can't do again, I will provide you a solution

Comment: Calling `strlen()` with an `int *` array?

Comment: Im trying to move the numbers are repeats itself to another array,

Comment: Also, do not call `strlen()` in the condition of a loop; it leads to bad performance, especially if the strings are 20 KiB long rather than a few bytes long.

Comment: @Jonathan      Ideal way to check in that situation will be?

Comment: Erm, aren't you calling `sizeof()` on a pointer now?  How does that help?

Comment: If you are dealing with strings, then you calculate their lengths once: `len1 = strlen(str1); len2 = strlen(len2);` outside the loops, and then iterate `for (i = 0; i < len1; i++) for (j = 0; j < len2; j++) { ... }`.  If you are changing the strings in the loops, you think hard about how to avoid reinvoking `strlen()` on each iteration.